# Is in the Python something like method findNext() in string?

Tags: python, string, parsing, find

E.g. I have got text:

"John got up. John went to the cinema. John washed his hand."

Now I would like to find first "John" and do something, then I would like to go to next "John" and do something, so I need to use something like `findNext()`, which considers the actual position, so it will not be finding from the beginning, but from the actual position.

Comment: Why not use a regular expression and `findall`?

Comment: findAll is not solution in my case. I need to find specific word, do something and after that go further.

Comment: *"do something"* like what? Where's **your code**, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 7):

The find-Method has a `start`-argument:

```
text = "John got up. John went to the cinema. John washed his hand."
pos = -1 
while True:
    pos = text.find('John', pos + 1)
    if pos == -1:
        break
    do_something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to parse a html/xml document, try using [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), Installation instructions on site. Then you can do something like,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text_in_string)
list = soup.findAll('id')
for each_id in list:
     #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to print all the nu bers which exists just next to `<id>`

```
>>> s = '''<text>ala
<id>1
<text>david
<id>2
<text>john
<id>3
<text>gregory
<id>4
<text>dominic
<id>5
<text>david
<id>2'''
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=<id>)\d+', s)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, what Daniel has written. But as a generator:

```
def nextIndex(string: str, text: str, start: int=0):
    while True:
        try:
            start = text.index(string, start)
            yield start
            start += 1
        except ValueError:
            raise StopIteration

text = "John got up. John went to the cinema. John washed his hand."

for i in nextIndex('John', text):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand what you what but based on your post, perhaps, it could be something like this:

```
x = 'John'
y = ['got up','went to the cinema', 'washed hands']
for i in y:
    print (x + ' ' + i)
```

This is the output:

```
John got up
John went to the cinema
John washed hands
```